# Jekyll version questions

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

If I run `jekyll -v` in terminal, I got this:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin19/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/opt in PATH, mode 040777
jekyll 4.1.0
```

But if I run `gem list jekyll`, it says I have another version of jekyll:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

jekyll (2.4.0)
jekyll-coffeescript (1.2.2)
jekyll-gist (1.5.0)
jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
jekyll-sass-converter (1.5.2)
jekyll-watch (1.5.1)
```

Does it mean I have two different versions of Jekyll installed? and how can I choose to use the old version 2.4.0? and is it possible to uninstall the 4.1.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am answering both of your questions:

1. > How can I choose to use the old version `2.4.0`?

   So, it is actually done through `Gemfile` in the project. Just mention `gem 'jekyll', '2.4.0'` in your Gemfile.
2. > Is it possible to uninstall the `4.1.0`?

   Yes. Run `gem uninstall Jekyll --version 4.1.0`

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've followed your steps, but it still doesn't seem to work,

Comment: 1. I created a new Gemfile with gem 'jekyll', '2.4.0', then I tried to run jekyll -v to check the jekyll version, but it says:

.../Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin19/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/opt in PATH, mode 040777
Traceback...(too long)
.../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:290:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'jekyll (= 2.4.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. (Bundler::GemNotFound)

but it shows up when I run gem list jekyll, why?

Comment: 2. When I run `gem uninstall jekyll --version 4.1.0`, I got this:

`Gem 'jekyll' is not installed`,

Question, if 4.1.0 is not installed, why it shows up when I run `jekyll -v' in the project that doesn't have a `Gemfile`.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin19/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/opt in PATH, mode 040777
jekyll 4.1.0
```

Comment: but if I run `gem list jekyll` anywhere, I can see jekyll installed:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

jekyll (2.4.0)
jekyll-coffeescript (1.2.2)
jekyll-gist (1.5.0)
jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
jekyll-sass-converter (1.5.2)
jekyll-watch (1.5.1)
```

Sorry, I have to say I'm not very familiar with Ruby, Gem, and Node, thank you for your patient.

Comment: @cg2017 Have you install Ruby through brew? or RVM ? Use RVM to install Ruby https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: yes, I've installed Ruby with brew by following this guide, https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/, thanks for answering the question, I finally got the jekyll v4.1.0 uninstalled, I'm not sure how I did though.

Comment: @cg2017 I would suggest to more on safer side by installing through "Rbenv" https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/#rbenv .  Remove Ruby with 'brew remove ruby'

Comment: Well, i thought this question has already been closed, but thanks @brg.